# Is there a condensed way of adding multiple event listeners each with different functions to the same group of elements?

Tags: javascript

I would ideally like to add event listeners to a single group of elements, `topLevelDesktopNavDropdownItems` , in some kind of object syntax like {event: function, event: function}. Or is there another way to do this? Here is my current code:

```
topLevelDesktopNavDropdownItems.forEach( 
    element => element.addEventListener('mouseenter', topLevelNavItemMouseOver)
);

topLevelDesktopNavDropdownItems.forEach(
    element => element.addEventListener('mouseleave', topLevelNavItemMouseOut)
);

topLevelDesktopNavDropdownItems.forEach(
    element => element.addEventListener('keydown', topLevelNavItemLinkKeyDown)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the same array 3 times, iterate over it once:

```
topLevelDesktopNavDropdownItems.forEach((element) => {
  element.addEventListener('mouseenter', topLevelNavItemMouseOver);
  element.addEventListener('mouseleave', topLevelNavItemMouseOut);
  element.addEventListener('keydown', topLevelNavItemLinkKeyDown);
});
```

If you think that's too repetitive, you can put the listeners into an object and iterate over the object:

```
const handlers = {
  mouseenter: topLevelNavItemMouseOver,
  mouseleave: topLevelNavItemMouseOut,
  keydown: topLevelNavItemLinkKeyDown,
};
for (const element of topLevelDesktopNavDropdownItems) {
  for (const [event, handler] of Object.entries(handlers)) {
    element.addEventListener(event, handler);
  }
}
```

A couple suggestions regarding naming:

- The `mouseover` event is not the same thing as the `mouseenter` event, Similarly, `mouseleave` is not exactly the same as `mouseout`. (One version propagates via bubbling/capturing, the other doesn't. If the elements have children, this makes a big difference.) For precision, consider naming the handlers exactly the same as the event they're listening for.
- If you have lots of handlers like this, prefixing them all with `topLevelNavItem` may get undesirably verbose. To isolate their scope to hopefully make the prefixes less necessary, consider defining them inside a function:

```
const addDropdownListeners = () => {
  const mouseOverHandler = (event) => {
    // ...
  };
  // ...
```

Or define them inline with the object:

```
const dropdownHandlers = {
  mouseenter: (event) => {
    // ...
  }
  // ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was all great stuff. I went with your first suggestion of only iterating over the array once, fixed my function names to use mouseenter/leave to reflect their true purpose, and tightened up my naming conventions a bit. Thank you again!